# Leading constraint within a stackview with leading distribution

Tags: ios, swift

I have several views within a vertical stackview with leading alignment. 
And I want the button has 16 left spacing.
I tried put a leading constraint but I get a conflict.

The 3 views you can see bellow are inside of the stackview.

[image]

I create a view and add the button as subview.
Is it a good approach?

[image]

What should I've change?

Comment: is your button located in stack view?

Comment: Yes all the views are inside of the stackview.

Comment: Then how can you set constraint to `button`, you have to give leading constraint to `stackview`.
Button will take only `height` and `width` or `aspect ratio`  when it was in stack.

Comment: I guess button has an intrinsic size. And the problem is the leading constraint and not de size. I'm missing something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416570/9136962

Comment: Ok, I've set a fixed height and width constraint. But I still cant set a leading constraint without conflicts.

Comment: You have to embed the button in a `View` and account for that said leading constraint between the `Button` and the `View`. There is no direct way to define relative spacing constraint in a `StackView` environment other than the `Spacing` of the stack view.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solutions**

1. Select button -> Embed in horizontal stackview
2. add dummyview at 1st position of `horizational stackview`, set width constraint and set `clear` color
3. play around alignment adjustments of horizontal stack view
4. add space between `dummyview` and `button`

**-- or --**

> suggested implementation from @nayem from comments.

1. Remove button
2. Add `UIView` as subview to `stackview`
3. Add button as subview to `UIView`
4. Add constraints to button

Comment: Is similar to add it as a subview and the apply a leadingconstraint. Is it a less nested approach?

Comment: Yes, it is.but using stack views makes sense than making complication with constraints. its up to you. if you have any better approach, post here. Thanks!